# Difference between shutdown -r and shutdown -P?

Tags: shutdown

What's the difference between `shutdown -r` and `shutdown -P`?

Answer (score 6):

You can get information about commands by typing:

```
man <command>
```

For the `shutdown` command you get:

```
OPTIONS
   -r     Requests that the system be rebooted after it has been brought down.

   -h     Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with  the  choice  as  to
          which left up to the system.

   -H     Requests that the system be halted after it has been brought down.

   -P     Requests that the system be powered off after it has been brought down.

   -c     Cancels a running shutdown.  TIME is not specified with this option, the first argument is MESSAGE.

   -k     Only send out the warning messages and disable logins, do not actually bring the system down.
```

Answer (score 4):

The shutdown process normally takes 30 seconds to allow each running service time to stop. Services are shutdown in alphabetical order.

**-r**    Reboot the system when shutdown is complete.

**-p**    Turn off the system without time-out or warning similar to **-h**

Answer (score -2):

`shutdown -p` will power off your system.

`shutdown -r` will restart it.

Comment: The right terminology in this case is 'reboot', not 'restart'.

Comment: [I guess Ubuntu is wrong](http://i.imgur.com/EMNoQ8E.png)

Comment: No, Ubuntu is perfectly right in that case :). The term **restart** is used to refer to a reboot when the operating system closes all programs and finalizes all pending input and output operations before initiating a soft reboot (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot_(computing))). But 'restart' is vague, and can also mean a reload of the current operating system without the boot loader - and because of this `man shutdouwn` use the term reboot for `-r` option.